# SQL DISTINCT посчитать

Tags: sql

Есть в таблице колонка "redirect", в ней могут быть несколько значений, а то и больше

- site
- group
- file

Вот у меня в таблице, 100 записей к примеру, я хочу вывести такой результат

```
site 12
site1 78
site2 10
```

То есть, в таблице 100 записей, записей с site = 12, с site1 78 и с site2 = 10

Использую для начала так

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `referal` FROM `users_new` WHERE `referal` LIKE '%site%';
```

Выводит название уник результатов, (site, site1, site2), а как высчитать в запросе количество строк, для каждого результата?...

Что бы писало не

```
site site1 site2
```

а

```
site 12
site1 78
site2 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать группировку по колонке `referal` и функцию `count`:

```
select `referal`, count(*) cnt
from `users_new`
where `referal` LIKE '%site%'
group by `referal`
```

Comment: WHERE... не нужно. Хотя для демонстрации - ок.

Comment: Там, в начальном примере, есть условие фильтрации. И по описанию данных там могут быть записи содержащие не только `%site%`.

Comment: WHERE нужно, ибо там префикс у всех site